# ERROR: UNIQUE constraint failed....but not when I use a SELECT * Statement (SQLite)

Tags: php, sqlite, sql-insert

I'm having a problem. I have a table in which I want to move its data into another table. When I do :
`INSERT INTO rosters SELECT * FROM rosters_test` 
All of the rows enter into the database. The problem is that the columns are out of order for the new data entered (the new data has `id` where `name` should be etc), therefore making the data incorrect and useless. 
[image: ohcrap]
 I have tried to be more specific about the insert statement, but that is where the `ERROR: UNIQUE constraint failed` occurs. I have a dual key on the `rosters` table which is the `id` and the `season`. I am trying to insert the 20142015 roster from the `rosters_test` table into the `rosters` table where the 20152016 and 20162017 rosters reside. 
 
Every row in the `roster_test` table is `20142015` for the `season` and I checked all 27 rows for repeat ids and there are none. These are the queries I tried:

```
INSERT INTO 'rosters'
SELECT 'number' AS 'number',  'name' AS 'name' , 'height' AS 'height', 'weight' AS 'weight', 'birthplace' AS 'birthplace', 'birthdate' AS 'birthdate', 'position' AS 'position', 'id' AS 'id', 'age' AS 'age', 'season' AS 'season', 'imageURL' AS 'imageURL'
FROM 'rosters_test' 

INSERT INTO 'rosters'  (number, name, height, weight, birthplace, birthdate ,position ,id ,age ,season, imageURL) 
SELECT 'number',  'name' , 'height', 'weight', 'birthplace', 'birthdate', 'position', 'id', 'age' , 'season', 'imageURL'
FROM 'rosters_test'
```

I also tried things such as rosters_test.number AS rosters.number as well. Nothing is working: Here is the schema of the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE 'rosters_test' ('number' INTEGER, 'name' TEXT, 'height' INTEGER, 'weight' INTEGER, 'birthplace' TEXT, 'birthdate' TEXT, 'position' TEXT, 'id' INTEGER, 'age' INTEGER, 'season' INTEGER, 'imageURL' TEXT)
```

I had a dual key on the `rosters_test` table at one point too.

```
CREATE TABLE 'rosters' ('position' TEXT, 'id' INTEGER, 'weight' INTEGER, 'height' TEXT, 'imageURL' TEXT, 'birthplace' TEXT, 'age' INTEGER, 'name' TEXT, 'birthdate' TEXT, 'number' INTEGER, 'season' INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY('id','season'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` and explicity specify the columns (and their order) which you want for the `rosters` table:

```
INSERT INTO rosters (position, id, weight, height, imageURL, birthplace, age, name,
                     birthdate, number, season)
SELECT position, id, weight, height, imageURL, birthplace, age, name, birthdate,
       number, season
FROM rosters_test
```

Comment: Working on you answer.

Comment: You have `rosters_test` as column names. I put in the correct column names as so....`INSERT INTO rosters (position, id, weight, height, imageURL, birthplace, age, name,
                     birthdate, number, season)
VALUES
SELECT position, id, weight, height, imageURL, birthplace, age, name,
       birthdate, number, season
FROM rosters_test`  but still get a syntax error `near select`

Comment: I changed the id column names to `id` instead of `rosters_test`.  I don't know why you had that there.

Comment: Reload the page, I removed `VALUES` which should not be there.

Comment: " 
I changed the id column names to id instead of rosters_test. I don't know why you had that there"  I had it as roster_test.id at one point.

Comment: This updated query works! I will take note of the proper syntax for future reference. Thanks for the help = )

Comment: I edited the `rosters_test` out of the query in the question since that was not part of the problem. (that was a remnant of another query)